# Individual axis limits with scale(expand) and scale=free in facetted ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Treatment=c("A", "B","A","B"), Value=c(3,4, 20,2), SE=c(1,1,5,1), Type=c("c1","c1","c2","c2")) 

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Treatment, Value,fill=Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", col="Black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Value + SE, ymin=Value), col="black") +
  facet_wrap(~Type, scale="free_y") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA),
        strip.background = element_blank())
p1
```

I want to remove the white space between bar and x-axis:

```
p1 + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

This also removes white space between the geom and the maximum of the y-axis. One way to prevent this is to control the limits of the y-axis

```
p1 + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits=c(0,26))
```

But now panel c1 has lots of white space, as `limits` apparently overrides `scale="free"`, which is especially irrating when the panels are arranged in columns.
So, i need to have the `expand`-argument and `scale="free"` active at the same time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a `geom_blank()`:

Please be considerate and try not to confound the user! This type of transformation can be dangerous!

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Treatment=c("A", "B","A","B"), Value=c(3,4, 20,2), SE=c(1,1,5,1), Type=c("c1","c1","c2","c2")) 

ggplot(df, aes(Treatment, Value,fill=Treatment)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", col="Black") +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Value + SE, ymin=Value), col="black") +
        geom_blank(aes(y=Value + SE + 1)) +
        facet_wrap(~Type, scale="free_y") +
        theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
              panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA),
              strip.background = element_blank()) + 
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Or:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Treatment, Value,fill=Treatment)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", col="Black") +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Value + SE, ymin=Value), col="black") +
        geom_blank(aes(y=Value + 2 * SE)) +
        facet_wrap(~Type, scale="free_y") +
        theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
              panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA),
              strip.background = element_blank()) + 
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you, since the plots are arranged in columns, and have indivual axes, i hope the viewer wont be confused. But its important to point it out.